# insertSubview() covers the whole Mainview even though inserted at 0

Tags: swift, xcode, view, uibutton, subview

I insert a UIView into a UIButton with following code:

```
        let backgroundView = UIView()
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        blueButton.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueButton.leadingAnchor),
            backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueButton.trailingAnchor),
            backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueButton.topAnchor),
            backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueButton.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

The promlem is that the backgroundView covers the whole button and I only see the red field instead of the button (its an image) with a red background (my subView).

This is the storyboard part of my image. I don´t do something else in the code with this buttons with the exception of trying to put a subView into:

[image]

**My goal** is to have a circle background like in the picture below. For example the red circle button has a rounded red (but brighter than the buttons red) backgroundView.The standard background of the button should stay the same.

[image]

I also tried to send the subView into the background but it didn´t work for me:

```
blueButton.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundView)
```

I reduced the alpha value of the subview to see if the button image is still there.

```
for view in blueButton.subviews {
    view.alpha = 0.5
}
```

And it is:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the purpose of setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`then adding the constraints yourself?

Comment: I´m not sure, have this code from stackoverflow. But without this row it doesn´t work. It would remove the whole view.

Comment: Show your whole code including the image part

Comment: i edited my question. I do nothing with the buttons except try to add a subview.

Comment: What is the purpose of injecting an extra view inside a button? A button already _has_ a background color _and_ a background image, so what is _your_ view supposed to do that they cannot? Why not just configure the button as intended rather than trying to mess with its private internals?

Comment: I again edited my question^^ Thank you for your response

Comment: Well if you want a button image that is a red circle with a paler red circle around that, why not make that whole thing the button image? Or make the paler red circle the `backgroundImage`?

Comment: matt, that would be my next choice. I just can´t get it in my head why the subview covers the whole button although i inserted it in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not inject extra subviews into a button. If the goal is to make the background color of the button red, set its `backgroundColor` to `.red`. If the goal is to put something behind the button image, that is what the `backgroundImage` is for. Or just make the button image look like the image you really want.

I made this button:

[image]

It looks a lot like your picture. Here's the code:

```
let im = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)).image {
    ctx in
    UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2).setFill()
    ctx.cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    ctx.cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20))
}
b.setImage(im.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```

I think that's a lot better than messing with unwanted illegal subviews.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, thank you very much for your effort!